# See when someone else is typing

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I made a chat application using socket.io

I wanted to make a feature that tells someone when the other user is typing a message. Initially my code was working, but for some reason it stopped. The chat function works fine.

#### Client Side

```
//Query DOM
var message = document.getElementById('message');
    handle = document.getElementById('handle'),
    btn = document.getElementById('send'),
    output = document.getElementById('output'),
    feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

//emit Events
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    socket.emit('chat', {
        message: message.value,
        handle: handle.value
    });
});

message.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    socket.emit('typing', handle.value);
});

//Listen for events
socket.on('chat', function(data){
    feedback.innerHTML = "";
    output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.handle  + ' </strong>' + data.message + ' </p>';
});

// socket.on('typing', function(data){
//     feedback.innerHTML = '<p><em>' + data + ' is typing a message....</em></p>';
// });

socket.on('typing', function(data){
    if (data) {
      feedback.innerHTML = '<p><em>' + data + ' is typing...</em></p>';
    } else {
      feedback.innerHTML = ''
    }
});
```

#### Server Side

```
var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Made socket connection', socket.id);

    socket.on('chat', function(data) {
        io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Just so you know, the first is _client side_ code, and the second is _server side_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server side code does not appear to have a function to respond to the "typing" event that your client sends to it.

Within your

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('Made socket connection', socket.id);

    socket.on('chat', function(data) {
        io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
    });
});
```

block you need to include a response the server can send to the client(s) when it receives a 'typing' event from the client.

something like

```
socket.on('typing', function(data){
    io.sockets.emit('userState', {user: bleh, typing: 
    true})
})
```